# AngularJS- How to deal with transformed data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

### Situation

I get collection of data in the form:

```
[{
  xRatio: 0.2,
  yRatio: 0.1,
  value: 15
 }, {
  xRatio: 0.6,
  yRatio: -0.3,
  value: 8
}]
```

I want to display this data in a `ng-repeat`. But before I can display this data I have to convert the relational data to absolute data in the form of

```
[{
  x: 120,
  y: 110,
  value: 15
 }, {
  x: 160,
  y: 70,
  value: 8
}]
```

To do this I use a function inside the `ng-repeat`, but this converter function returns a new collection every time called and therefore the model never stabilizes and angular throws an `infinite loop exception` and gives up.

The html code is,

```
<div ng-repeat="result in results">    
  <div>
    <heat-map data="convertResult(result)"></heat-map>
  </div>   
</div>
```

The heatmap directive interpolates and displays the data.

**My question is**: How do I handle this situation without clutter my initial collection with the generated values?

Hence the single elements of the results collection does not change I thought about an `one-time-binding` on the converter function but that does not work.

### Edit:

I also want to be able to remove items from the converted collection as well as from the original one.

Comment: You could transform the list of results `results` before passing it to ng-repeat and storing it in a new field, maybe in the controller. So the controller can re-transform whenever the original data changes.

the html would look like this then
    <div ng-repeat="result in transformed">
    ...
        <heat-map data="result">....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Either use the `::` operator in your `ng-repeat` to prevent re-evaluation of the expression:

   ```
   <div ng-repeat = "item in ::convert(items)" >
   ```
2. Otherwise you could manually convert the data before you feed it to `ng-repeat`:

   JS

   ```
   $scope.cleanData = convert( $scope.ratioData );
   ```

   HTML

   ```
   <div ng-repeat = "item in cleanData" >
   ```
3. Or do the conversion when you need it. In your directive heatmap, define `data` as an expression binding using the symbol `&` and in the directive controller use

   ```
    scope.data()
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But how do i track which converted data set belong to which original set?

Comment: Is it bad to use a custom `$filter` for that kind of thing?

Comment: no the custom filter produces the same `infdig` problem

Comment: The onetime binding (`::`) does not work because even the OTB does check the value twice and these two arrays are eval but not the same...

Comment: I'll go with the second approach and id's to track changes

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a converted version of your data, in `ng-repeat`?
Something like this (in your controller):

```
var convertedData = data.map(function datum) {
    return convert(datum); 
});
function convert(datum) {
  // ... your conversion logic here ...
}
```

And then use `convertedData` in `ng-repeat`?